# Deleting a list of messages in discord-py

Tags: python, discord.py, rate-limiting

StackOverflow community.
I am making a trivia command on my discord fun bot.

I want it to delete the messages it sends when the game is over.

I wanna do this by adding all the message objects to a list then deleting all of them at the end of the command.

I know you can iterate through the list then deleting them 1 by 1, but I am very scared of rate limitations. Is there a way to delete lists of messages in just 1 API call?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.delete_messages

`await TextChannel.delete_messages(messages)`

Another option is that if you know the maximum time of a trivia game, you can use `delete_after` kwarg in send():
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send

`await Messageable.send('content', delete_after=SECONDS)`

If I recall correctly, discord.py handles the ratelimits for you, so you shouldn't worry much. (double check as im not sure!)